# Пространство элементарных исходов через Numpy

Tags: python, list, numpy, теория-вероятностей

Надо построить пространство элементарных исходов используя Numpy. Допустим после трех бросков монеты результатом было бы:

```
[[0,0,0],
[0,0,1],
[0,1,0],
[1,0,0],
[0,1,1],
[1,1,0],
[1,0,1],
[1,1,1]]
```

где 0-'орел' и 1-'решка', то есть нужно перебрать все возможные комбинации не повторяясь. Есть ли простой способ сделать это через Numpy?

Comment: from itertools import product; product(range(2), repeat=3)

Comment: да, itertools это упрощает, но мне необходимо сделать именно через numpy

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11144513/7485582